# Create a Model for a custom table

Tags: magento-1.9, model

I created a custom table and would like to show the data from this table in a grid in admin section. I have created configuration for viewing the admin page. But there is an error while getting data from the table.

**The error is** :

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in`

My table name is "**product_edit_details**".

the config file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
    <modules>
        <Buildnext_Producteditrequest>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Buildnext_Producteditrequest>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <producteditrequest>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>BuildnextProducteditrequest</module>
                    <frontName>producteditrequest</frontName>
                </args>
            </producteditrequest>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <producteditrequest>
                    <file>producteditrequest.xml</file>
                </producteditrequest>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend> 
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <producteditrequest>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Buildnext_Producteditrequest</module>
                    <frontName>producteditrequest</frontName>
                </args>
            </producteditrequest>
        </routers>
    </admin> 
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <producteditrequest module="producteditrequest">
                <title>Producteditrequest</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="producteditrequest">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>producteditrequest/adminhtml_producteditrequest</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </producteditrequest>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <producteditrequest>
                            <title>Producteditrequest Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </producteditrequest>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>   
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <producteditrequest>
                    <file>producteditrequest.xml</file>
                </producteditrequest>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>  
    <global>
        <models>
            <producteditrequest>
                <class>Buildnext_producteditrequest_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>producteditrequest_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </producteditrequest>
            <producteditrequest_mysql4>
                <class>Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <producteditrequest>
                        <table>product_edit_details</table>
                    </producteditrequest>
                </entities>
            </producteditrequest_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <producteditrequest_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Buildnext_Producteditrequest</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </producteditrequest_setup>
            <producteditrequest_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </producteditrequest_write>
            <producteditrequest_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </producteditrequest_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <producteditrequest>
                <class>Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Block</class>
            </producteditrequest>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <producteditrequest>
                <class>Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Helper</class>
            </producteditrequest>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**/Producteditrequest/Model/Producteditrequest.php**

```
class Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Model_Producteditrequest extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('producteditrequest/producteditdetails');
    }
}
```

I have doubt regarding this line $this->_init('producteditrequest/producteditdetails'); -- My table name is product_edit_details tried giving       $this->_init('producteditrequest/product_edit_details'); but was not working so i removed the underscores after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353502/magento-create-table-with-custom-module) answer.

**/Producteditrequest/Model/Mysql4/Producteditrequest.php**

```
class Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Model__Mysql4_Producteditrequest 
      extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('producteditrequest/producteditdetails','pdt_edit_id');
    }
}
```

**/Producteditrequest/Model/Mysql4/Producteditrequest/Collection.php**

```
class Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Model_Mysql4_Producteditrequest_Collection 
      extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_init('producteditrequest/producteditdetails');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `producteditrequest` in place of `producteditdetails` in `init()` function

Comment: I have made that change in following locations but still getting that same error /Producteditrequest/Model/Producteditrequest.php,/Producteditrequest/Model/Mysql4/Producteditrequest.php,/Producteditrequest/Model/Mysql4/Producteditrequest/Collection.php. Could it be something with the table name ? Or the configuration?

Comment: Compilation is enable? Did you flush cache?

Comment: Yes i have flushed the cache... Not sure about what you meant by "Compilation" :) sorry about that....

Comment: Check `System > tools > compilation` . Disable it

Comment: Its already disabled. -->  Compiler Status
 Disabled
Compilation State
 Not Compiled

Comment: Can you please change following extending class. Resource model set `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` and for collection set `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`

Comment: Actually i'm new to magnto. I have changed the extending class of /Producteditrequest/Model/Mysql4/Producteditrequest/Collection.php
to Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract. But not sure which file to change for Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract

Comment: `/Producteditrequest/Model/Mysql4/Producteditrequest.php` Just copy paste following class definition `class Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Model_Mysql4_Producteditrequest 
      extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` .

You have added double underscore(__) in this class. I have fixed this in above line.
Let me know if its worked for you.

Comment: Made that change and flushed Magento Cahce. But still getting that error. :(

Comment: Replace `Mysql4` this with `Resource` in all files. also in your `config.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Follow bellow steps :

Step : 1 `config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
    <modules>
        <Buildnext_Producteditrequest>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Buildnext_Producteditrequest>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <producteditrequest>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>BuildnextProducteditrequest</module>
                    <frontName>producteditrequest</frontName>
                </args>
            </producteditrequest>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <producteditrequest>
                    <file>producteditrequest.xml</file>
                </producteditrequest>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend> 
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <producteditrequest>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Buildnext_Producteditrequest</module>
                    <frontName>producteditrequest</frontName>
                </args>
            </producteditrequest>
        </routers>
    </admin> 
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <producteditrequest module="producteditrequest">
                <title>Producteditrequest</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="producteditrequest">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>producteditrequest/adminhtml_producteditrequest</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </producteditrequest>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <producteditrequest>
                            <title>Producteditrequest Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </producteditrequest>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>   
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <producteditrequest>
                    <file>producteditrequest.xml</file>
                </producteditrequest>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>  
    <global>
        <models>
            <producteditrequest>
                <class>Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>producteditrequest_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </producteditrequest>
            <producteditrequest_mysql4>
                <class>Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>        
                    <producteditrequest>
                        <table>product_edit_details</table>
                    </producteditrequest>
                </entities>
            </producteditrequest_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <producteditrequest_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Buildnext_Producteditrequest</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </producteditrequest_setup>
            <producteditrequest_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </producteditrequest_write>
            <producteditrequest_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </producteditrequest_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <producteditrequest>
                <class>Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Block</class>
            </producteditrequest>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <producteditrequest>
                <class>Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Helper</class>
            </producteditrequest>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Step : 2 /Buildnext/Producteditrequest/Model/Producteditrequest.php

```
class Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Model_Producteditrequest extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init("producteditrequest/producteditrequest");
    }
}
```

Step : 3 Buildnext/Producteditrequest/Model/Mysql4/Producteditrequest.php

```
class _Producteditrequest_Model_Mysql4_Producteditrequest extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('producteditrequest/producteditrequest','pdt_edit_id');
    }
}
```

Step : 4 Buildnext/Producteditrequest/Model/Mysql4/Producteditrequest/Collection.php

```
class Buildnext_Producteditrequest_Model_Mysql4_Producteditrequest_Collection 
      extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_init('producteditrequest/producteditrequest');
    }
}
```

Step : 5 Buildnext/Producteditrequest/Model/Mysql4/sql/producteditrequest_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('producteditrequest/producteditrequest')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('producteditrequest/producteditrequest')} (
  `pdt_edit_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `created_at` datetime NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pdt_edit_id`)    
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");  

$installer->endSetup();
```

Step : 6 app\etc\modules\Buildnext_Producteditrequest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Buildnext_Producteditrequest>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Buildnext_Producteditrequest>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step : 7 Refresh all magento Cache to admin side System -> Cache Management

Answer (score 1):

For creating the custom model please create the model,resource and collection files inside the model folder.

[image]

Add the following code in the collection.php file.

```
/*
 app\code\local\Display\Customgrid\Model\Resource\Displaygrid\Collection.php
 */

 <?php

 class Display_Customgrid_Model_Resource_Displaygrid_Collection extends     Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
/**
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('customgrid/displaygrid');
}
 }
```

Please click here for full code.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/code-snippets/create-custom-model-magento/